# Difference in height of element at page load

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

As this question evolved, the proper title should actually be: **Difference in body width at page load.**. It also has to do with pictures being resized in the page. If we remove the pictures, the difference is gone.

Please note that this question **does not require a practical solution** (I could just delay the script execution with a setTimeout() and the problem would be solved). I am asking because I would like to understand the technical aspects of this behaviour.

---

While writing a script for an answer here, on SO, I discovered a weird difference in height of an element if calculated at page load or later on.

Here's the snippet:

```js
document.initPictures = function() {
  $('.resizeMe').css({
    'height': $('#theContainer .col-sm-6').eq(1).height() + 6,
    'display': 'flex',
    'flex-direction': 'column',
    'transition': 'height .4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.55, 0.2)'
  });
  $('.resizeMe img').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.resizeMe').append('<div style="flex-basis: 50%; background-image: url(' + src + '); background-size:cover; background-position: center center"' + '</div>');
    $(this).remove();
  })
};
document.resizePictures = function() {
  if ($('#theContainer').outerWidth() > 768) {
    $('.resizeMe').css({
      'height': $('#theContainer .col-sm-6').eq(1).height()
    });
  } else {
    $('.resizeMe').css({
      'height': $('.resizeMe').outerWidth()
    });
  }
};
$(window).resize(function() {
  document.resizePictures();
});
document.initPictures();
```

```css
.main-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
#theContainer {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row-fluid" id="theContainer">
  <div class="col-sm-6 resizeMe">
    <img class="filler" src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
    <img class="filler" src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image2.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img class="main-img" src="http://joombig.com/demo-extensions1/images/gallery_slider/Swan_large.jpg" />
  </div>
```

You'll notice I'm making the images in the first div 50% of the height of the image in second div (that was the requirement). On page load, second div's image height comes up short `6px` `$('#theContainer .col-sm-6').eq(1).height()` which I had to compensate for in the `initPictures()` function, but this compensation was not necessary in the `resizePictures()`, which happens on `$(window).resize()`.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome, but I've also tested it in latest FF. Same behaviour.

I'd be really happy to understand what's up with this difference. Where does it come from? Does it have to do with Bootstrap, with jQuery? Or with what?

**NOTE**: When testing, I also tried to use `innerheight()` and `outerHeight()` hoping I could get around "the bug". They are all `6px` short at that point.

**Another NOTE**: Just for testing purposes, I made a [jsFiddle](//jsfiddle.net/websiter/9a4hbLu7/) for this. When I load it normally, as a fiddle, it has the same bug and the compensation is necessary. When viewed in [full screen mode](//jsfiddle.net/websiter/9a4hbLu7/embedded/result/) the compensation is no longer necessary and it actually renders the left column `6px` shorter because of the compensation.

---

Update: after some thorough testing using AvArt's idea of logging this, it came out it all started from `body`s width. By default, for no particular reason, it's not `100vw` when the page loads.

You could checkout [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/o1g5x5m6/10/), if loaded at viewport widths above `(768 - 17)px`. For some reason, some of you never experience this "bug", but I'm assuming some did, since the question has been voted up.
However, if you uncomment the last line of CSS, the bug vanishes.

So, with body having a different width for a short period of time at pageload, the width of `.col-sm-6` was affected, affecting the `auto` height of the contained image, affecting the column height. The `6px` difference (and sometimes 7) was resulting from the images' particular height/width ratio, but the starting difference in body's width was 17px.

Now, the question is still open: **why does the `body` element have a 17px difference in width at pageload from the `100vw`, which should be default, at widths above (768 - 17)px**?

The funny thing is it **has** to do with the pictures, because if we remove the pictures from `HTML`, the difference is gone!

Anyone familiar enough with how browsers work and how CSS gets applied initially to shed some light on this behaviour?

Sorry for the lengthy explanations, it's just something I couldn't figure out for days, so I just had to ask and find out.

---

Updated [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/o1g5x5m6/13/).

Comment: Images have not been loaded when you call it initially.

Comment: @epascarello If what you say is true, than the div should not have any height, as it doesn't have any content that has height, right? If I change the image with another one with a different aspect ratio, there is the same 6px difference.

Comment: @epascarello I just checked source code from both SO snippet and jsFiddle. They both wrap the script part of any snippet in a `window.onload=function(){...})` wrapper and, as far as I know, that only fires after all the page has loaded, including images. This is driving me nuts...

Comment: Hmm interesting. Would you mind trying out [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/o1g5x5m6/6/) and tell us what you're seeing in the console log?

Comment: @AvAvt it depends on `result` frame width. I'll make some tests when I get to a desktop. They don't always differ.

Comment: No difference between initPictures and resizePictures (chrome, safari, FF, O) http://dx-creation.com/js/34140586.html

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu yeah I understand the scaling. The result you described is quite strange because in the case of image not loaded, it would be either 20px on Chrome, or height = width on Firefox (since firefox assume images being loaded are square). In any case a consistent lack of 6px is strange indeed.

Comment: It's not always 6px. It has to be some percent. Sometimes it's 7. I'll do some systematic tests and update with the results.

Comment: I have yet to explain the reason, because I can't see it on my computers (2 PCs and a Mac book, under different internet connections). Just want to comment to suggest that instead of using a 6px compensation, you should first leave it be (with possible shortage of height), and recalculate `.resizeMe`'s height in `$('.main-img').load()`. That way you can have something to show at first and still manage to get the correct height before the user can notice it.

Comment: After some [thorough testing with various scripts](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/o1g5x5m6/9/) based on @AvArt's idea of logging them all, i believe I got to the bottom of this. It actually has to do with `body`s width. In the fiddle above, remove the last line of CSS and test it on a window of ~ 750px. You'll notice on page load the body has a width that's lower than afterwards. (h2 holds body's width). It has to do with the negative margin relation between `row` and `cols`, I think. When I set `body{width: 100vw;}` everything is fixed. It drove me nuts for days...

Comment: By the way, I'm still looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources. Why doesn't `body` have a `width` equal to viewport `width` by default? Is this caused by Bootstrap? Does it have to do with negative margins on `row`s?

Comment: No, `<body>` will have the height of the content of the document. `<html>` tag too. No matter what library or framework do you use. So if you have a content of images, while images doesn't load the height will be zero. The difference of 6px it's because that: `'height': $('#theContainer .col-sm-6').eq(1).height() + 6`. To avoid the problem of initial height I make sometimes `html, body { height: 100%; }`. Your problem you can fix listening the onload event **in images** (or in whole window like `$(window).on('load')`, with this mode, the inner script will execute while images are full loaded

Comment: It has something to do with the scrollbar. The body width differs 17px on chrome. You can check it by using body `{overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: Yes, you are right, @AurelianoFarSuau. If you have the time to document this and provide it as an answer, it would be my pleasure to award you the reward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the Javascript execution order. `initPictures()` must be executed before you check the body width. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1g5x5m6/25/)

Comment: With a great deal of help from you, including the comment under the question, I have finally found the answer. **The difference appears when the unstyled content requires a scrollbar and the styled content does not, or vice-versa**. And it makes a lot of sense. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: And when I say "unstyled" I actually mean "content without external CSS applied". The inline CSS is applied by browser when deciding if the page will or will not have a scrollbar. Try the "fixed" fiddle at a width of 1777px and height just enough to hide the small numbers. Not so fixed, is it? Even with 0 height and width on img. :) The answer in my comment above is, technically, the correct one. But you deserve the bounty in full, from my point of view. Cheers!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You're right. On my fiddle the scrollbar is added instead of removed :P. Check this one: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1g5x5m6/22/). If you find it to be correct I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I was wrong. The problem is the Javascript execution order. It's lame how no one (including me) saw this before. I'm so sorry.

Comment: The only foolproof solution around the bug is `body{width: 100vw;}`. But I wasn't looking for a solution, I was looking for an answer. And I have it now.

Comment: Here is [the correct solution](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/o1g5x5m6/26/). It's right on any screen size. I removed the initial `+6` adjustment, too

Answer (score 3):

The `17px` difference you're seeing is the **scrollbar width**.

**The document's width is unknown untill all assets are completely loaded, so it reserves some space for a possible scrollbar**. In practice, this means that `window.onLoad` will only execute when all images are loaded. While as jQuery's `ready` event will fire as soon as the DOM is loaded.

I've created a new Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/u7zgz25u/3/) demonstrating this behaviour. (To clear the images from cache, just change 1 of the colors in their url's).

When looking at http://jsfiddle.net/o1g5x5m6/20/ (your example without images), the `ready` and `window.onLoad` events are executed at (almost) the same time, before the actual rendering takes place, hence the page dimensions are known to the browser.

PS:
I've found an interesting Fiddle demonstrating the scrollbar width being taken into account by the browser rendering, despite a large enough `padding-right` being available: http://jsfiddle.net/9pAcp/2/

## Update

Some browsers implement a rendering delay (e.g. [Firefox documentation](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Nglayout.initialpaint.delay)), hence the difference between the initial width and the width after the images have loaded. If the images are loaded before the initial rendering delay, or there are no images, the browser can calculate the correct height, however, if the images are not loaded yet, and they have no known dimensions, the browser needs to wait for the images to load before it can calculate their size. Hence the possible difference between the estimated document size (with space reserved for a scrollbar), and the actual document size after `window.onLoad` has been triggered.

See http://jsfiddle.net/u7zgz25u/4/ for a demo on what happens when you define a fixed height for the images in HTML. The 17px difference is not there anymore.

Comment: When I delete the content: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1g5x5m6/16/). "the browser expects that a scrollbar might be needed" not :/

Comment: I'm not sure,  but this might be due to the fact that the height of the images is still being calculated, while the height of text is known way sooner. I'm trying to find a way to profile this.

Comment: I've updated my answer clarifying the behaviour you see.

Comment: Ok, I found it: browsers have a delay time before starting to render. It appears that the browser needs to wait for the images to load before being able to calculate the document's dimensions, hence the difference between the initial width and the width after `onLoad`. Initially it reserves space for the scrollbar due to the unkown size of the images. However, if the images are loaded before the delay expires, or there are no images (and the DOM has been fully loaded), there is no difference. (answer updated accordingly)

Comment: After some [more testing](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/o1g5x5m6/21/) it appears that the browser only calculates the scrollbar during page load **if it has reason to believe** the page contents will need one, not always. So it looks to me that, technically, even though rather short, [Aureliano's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34293896/1891677) answer is the correct one. Since he is also the first to make the correlation between the scrollbar and the source of the problem, I will award him the reward for this. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have a confirmed source for this case, but as i can see doing some experiment there are rendering problem with the flex box.

> you replace the 2 images that have a real height with a div that have
> images as backgound and so it lose it's height.
>
> The flex container
> recalc the height of this two image divs but with some render
> problem probably caused by the fact(as write on the comment) that the scrollbar take some space.
>
> jQuery calc the width without the scrollbar`$(window).width()` while the effective width of the viewport can be seen using the `window.innerWidth` native of javascript that is 17px more the jquery width.
>
> For some rendering reason the height of jquery is calculated with a visible scrollbar as you can see in the example below where i replaced the body width with `overflow:scroll`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1g5x5m6/19/)

I have concluded a similar work with this edits without using the flex-box:

```
$('.resizeMe,.cover-img').css({
  'height': $('#theContainer .col-sm-6').eq(1).height(),
  'transition': 'height .4s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.55, 0.2)'
});
$('.resizeMe img').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('.resizeMe').append('<div class="cover-img" style="background-image: url(' + src + '); height: '+$(this).height()+'px;"' + '</div>');
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Using divs with they heights, the effect is the same but without the approximation problem.

there the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9a4hbLu7/21/) with a possible solution.

another example without rendering problem, leaving the img tags without replacing them with divs and without calc the height with js:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9a4hbLu7/19/)

Comment: Emanuele, to my knowledge, Bootstrap 3 has nothing to do with `flexbox`. Bootstrap 4 will have the option to use flexbox for columns, but it will be optional and it is still under development as of this moment. Also, although I'm a big fan of flexbox and I personally think it should be the only model for layout-ing, I'm not using it at all here. What am I missing?

Comment: In your example you use the container `.resizeMe` with `display:flex;` and the  child div with `flex-basis: 50%;`.
Using normal block content with "not calculated" height there are no render problems.

Comment: You're right, I completely forgot about the inline CSS. However, it is not the cause of the initial difference. The correct technical answer (from everything I've read and tested) is Aureliano's. The difference only appears when the unstyled content has a scrollbar and the styled content does not have one.